# Mono-Server4, Apache2, and Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: apache2, mono

I have installed Ubuntu Server 14.04.2, Apache2 and Mono-Server2 and Mono-Server4 as I am trying to figure out how to resolve a compiler error.

My Googling just lead me in circles.

I have a test.aspx page which has the following code:
    1 + 2 = <%= (1+2).ToString() %>

I have a Web.conf with the following code:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

When requesting my test.aspx page I receive the following errors:

> Application Exception System.Web.Compilation.CompilationException :
>   Unhandled Exception:
>
> Description: Error compiling a resource required to service this
>   request. Review your source file and modify it to fix this error.
>   Details: : Unhandled Exception: Error origin: Compiler Error source
>   file: /test.aspx Exception stack trace:   at
>   System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly
>   (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath,
>   System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly
>   (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) [0x00000] in :0
>   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GenerateAssembly
>   (System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder abuilder,
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProviderGroup group,
>   System.Web.VirtualPath vp, Boolean debug) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BuildInner
>   (System.Web.VirtualPath vp, Boolean debug) [0x00000] in :0

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: I am still struggling with this, Can no one help?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest version of mono found here http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/

make sure you follow the instructions for ubuntu 13.10 or later

this should correct the mono installation -- worked for me (thanks to my son)